# Understanding a pattern in Chrome DevTools Memory Performance Graph

Tags: javascript, memory, scope, garbage-collection, setinterval

I am trying to understand how to prevent memory leaks when using timers. I believe the Chrome Dev Tools Performance tab (I am still learning about this feature) memory graph is showing me a bad pattern in terms of memory management. I believe it is a case of a "sawtooth" pattern each time a Timer is fired.

I have a simple [test case](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/HUz2ynPgKia8FYv3) (1. right click 'timer-adder.html', 2. click 'Preview' to get a preview of the loaded HTML) that involves using a constructor function to create objects that work as timers, in other words for each update, the DOM is changed inside a `setInterval` callback.

```
//...
start: function (initialTime, prefixedId) {
        let $display = document.getElementById(prefixedId + '-display');
        if ($display.style.display === 'none') { $display.style.display = 'block'; }
        $display.textContent = TimerHandler.cycle(initialTime);
        $display = null;
        return setInterval(function () {
            this.initialTime--;
            (this.initialTime === 0 && this.pause());
            document.getElementById(prefixedId + '-display').textContent = TimerHandler.cycle(this.initialTime);
        }.bind(this), 1000);
},
/...
```

Attempts to minimize leakage although not directly related to what I believe to be the problem at hand:

- assigning `$display` to `null` to make it collectible (garbage collection).
- clearing the interval;

What I identify as a bad pattern:
[image]
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv3yM.jpg) (zoomable)

A fair memory usage would translate to DevTools showing a horizontal line? What would be a safer approach to this side effect? Because, as the test is right now, I think that in the long run, multiple active timers would overload memory and thus result in a noticeable decrease in performance.

PS: As a newcomer, I hope this is a fair presentation of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the last part, the Garbagge Collector *was able to free that memory*. Thus there is no memory leaking.

Garbagge Collection is a complicated task, thats why V8 tries to minimize the number of stop-the-world collections. Or in other words: It only cleans up memory *if it needs it*.
In your case it doesn't. There is still enough space available.

If (a noticible amount of) memory persists across GC calls, then  you do have a memory leak.

> assigning `$display` to null to make it collectible (garbage collection).

Thats just unneccessary. `$display` is not accessed in the inner function, therefore it is viable for gc'ing after `init` executed. Reassigning it doesn't change that.

Comment: I see. I was wondering if there's any problem when a timer fires, because it is showing increase. Shouldn't it be collecting after each new timer fire, shouldn't it be leveled throughout?

Comment: No, why should the engine waste time on gc'ing?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that GC is a task with no specific interval. Is that right? And I think I'm not distilling what is confusing me. Maybe I should try asking (maybe it's out of this post's scope, sorry) what, in terms of code, is making the green and blue lines behave like a staircase, going up. Do you know?

Comment: Yes, GC runs when needed. And that "staircase" appears cause you allocate chunks of memory at once.